# Mac Terminal Bash awk change multiple file names to $NF output

Tags: bash, macos, awk, terminal

I have been working on this script to retrieve files from all the folders in my directory and trying to change their names to my desired output.

Before filename:
`Folder\actors\character\hair\haircurly1.dds`

After filename:
`haircurly1.dds`

I am working with over 12,000 textures with different names that I extracted from an archive. My extractor included the path to the folder where it extracted the files in each file name. For example, a file that should have been named `haircurly1.dds` was named `Folder\actors\character\hair\haircurly1.dds` during extraction.

```
cd ~/Desktop/MainFolder/Folder

find . -name '*\\*.dds' | awk -F\\ '{ print; print $NF; }'
```

This code retrieves every texture file that I am looking at containing backslashes (as I have already changed some of the files with other codes, however I want one that will change all of the files at once rather than me having to write specific codes for every folder for 12,000+ texture files)

I use print; and it sends me the file path:

`./Folder\actors\character\hair\haircurly1.dds`

I use print `$NF;` and it sends me the text after the awk separator:

`\`
`haircurly1.dds`

I would like every file name that this script runs through to be changed to the $NF output of the awk command. Anyone know how I can make my script change the file names to their `$NF` output?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please add a clear example of before and after filename?

Comment: Edited it for clarity.
Before filename: Folder\actors\character\hair\haircurly1.dds

After filename: haircurly1.dds

Comment: And they are all in the folder directly below? Try `for i in *\\*;do echo "$i" "${i##*\\}"; done` ? Change `echo` to `mv` if the filenames look alright.

Comment: They are in a complex tree of many different folders. For example, one file might be Folder\actors\character\hair\haircurly1.dds while another might be Folder\architecture\building1\window.dds

Comment: So you want the folder structure recreating as well? As `\ ` are just characters in the filenames.

Comment: Your script worked for one individual folder when I changed my directory to it, however do you know how it could be looped to search in every folder within the current directory?

Comment: If you have bash 4+ you can use globstar, `shopt -s globstar;for i in **/*\\*;do yadayada`

Comment: @123: OS X / MacOS is Bash 3.x ...

Comment: @l'L'l oh dear.

Comment: Indeed... apparently apple likes to be in with the "old"... :/

Comment: `mkdir /tmp/new; find . -name \*dds -exec cp {} /tmp/new \;` surely?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I think they want to keep the filestructure.

Comment: @123 Possibly :-) I read it as though they explicitly wanted to flatten it! Who knows?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Just going off their comment on the answer below.

Comment: @I'L'I I think Apple doesn't like GPL3.

Comment: Yes, I would like to keep the file structure

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I didn't even think about that, and I bet you're right - as the date coincides almost exactly. I have no idea what might be different about it, but interesting nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear but it SOUNDS like all you want to do is:

```
for file in *\\*; do
    mv -- "$file" "${file##*\\}"
done
```

If that's not all you want then edit your question to clarify your requirements.

Answer (score -2):

Have your awk command format and print a "mv" command, and pipe the result to bash. The extra single-quoting ensures bash treats backslash as a normal char.

```
find . -name '*\\*.dds' | awk -F\\ '{print "mv '\''" $0 "'\'' " $NF}' | bash -x
```

hth

Comment: That worked for changing the file names but it moved everything to the current directory out of their original folders.

Comment: @DevinWalker That's exactly what your question implies - it says you want to change the name from `X/Y/Z/haircut.dds` to `haircut.dds` which, by definition, means the current directory since no other is specified.

Comment: @MarkSetchell they are backslashes in the question.

Comment: No, it was \ backslashes, not forward slashes indicating I wanted to change the file names where there previously were blackslashes. Not forward slashes indicating directory path. Sorry for the miscommunication.

Comment: Mmmm... maybe stop using nasty Windowsy software on your lovely Mac :-)

Comment: Just trying to do my job handling and organizing these textures originally made on a nasty windows pc :-)